# Clearing selected table cell by a button click

Tags: javascript

I have a table that can select a cell by a java script function. I want to clear the selected cell by clicking the clear button. How to implement this by java script.

The cell selecting function is below;

```
function select_class(element){
    document.getElementById("clicked_cell"+previous_element).classList.remove('auto-style01');
    document.getElementById("clicked_cell"+element).classList.add('auto-style01');
    previous_element = element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just with `innerHTML` to empty:

```
  document.getElementById("clicked_cell"+element).innerHTML = "";
```

You should execute this line on clear button click.

Comment: not working above code when apply to a button @Marcos Pérez Gude

Comment: You need to adapt the code to your situation. The code you've attached is a little piece of nothing, we can't see your html structure at all. See that `+element` that you need to reference the correct cell.